# Expressing $ r = \cot(\theta) $ as an equation in terms of Cartesian coordinates $ (x,y) $.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I need to show this equation

$r = \cot(\theta)$ as $x$,$y$ using the following laws:

$x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$

$r^2=x^2+y^2$, $\tan(\theta)=\frac{y}{x}$

This is what I've done :

$$r = \cot(\theta) \\ 
r = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} \\
r^2=\frac{r\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\\
x^2+y^2=\frac{x}{\sin(\theta)}$$

Now, I'm stuck what should I do with $\sin(\theta)$?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You can write $\cot\theta$ as $r\cos\theta / r\sin\theta$, so you could say $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = x/y$$ Note that squaring both sides will introduce false solutions, since if $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs, they can't satisfy the equation (LHS and RHS would be of opposite sign, but that's hidden when you square).

Comment: @MPW I don't understand why? In my book is not a given fact that $\ cot(\theta)=x/y$ eventhough it pretty clear now since $\ tan(\theta)=y/x$ can you show it algebraic with the laws I've written above?

Comment: @MPW OH, I understand now, thank you!

Comment: YW${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use

$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

and $$\cot{\theta}=\frac{x}{y}$$

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Surely it is just $x^2 + y^2 = (\frac{x}{y})^2$?

By the way, I think you might mean $x^2+y^2$ instead of $x^2=y^2$ in your fourth line down :)

Comment: you'r right edited

Answer (score 0):

$$ r \tan \theta =1 $$

$$ r^2 \tan^2 \theta =1 $$

$$ ( x^2 +y^2) \cdot \dfrac{y^2}{x^2} = 1 $$

Littus?